# Simple ListPlot3D Example: Axes and Transpose Using ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am able to quickly create this minimal working example 3D Plot:

```
data = Table[Sin[2*Pi*x*(t - 4)]/x, {x, .0001, 2, .1}, {t, 5, 6, 0.1}];
ListPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"t, time", "x, distance", "h, height"}]
```

[image]

My problem is that I can't figure out how to format the data so that the "x, distance" axis and the "t,time" axis have the correct values. In this example, `x` should go from 0 to 2; it instead goes from 0 to 20. `t` should go from 5 to 6, and it instead goes from 0 to 10.

When doing it in 2D, and using `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`, the function `Transpose` can be used, or the data can be generated like this:

```
data2D = Table[{x, Sin[2*Pi*x*(1)]/x}, {x, .0001, 2, .1}];
ListPlot[data2D, ImageSize -> {600, 300} , GridLines -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How can I do this in 3D? I have tried a bunch of stuff, including:

```
data = Table[{t, Table[{x, Sin[2*Pi*x*t]/x}, {x, .0001, 2, .1}]}, {t, 1, 1.5, 0.5}]
```

And

```
data = Table[Table[{t, x, Sin[2*Pi*x*t]/x}, {x, .0001, 2, .1}], {t, 1, 1.5, 0.5}]
```

But these, among the many other attempts, don't seem to work. There are several similar examples on SE Mathematica, but I haven't found one that specifically addresses how to organize the data for a simple plot. The [wolfram documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) also doesn't elaborate very well.

Comment: Have you seen `DataRange`?

Comment: @J.M. That's a new one for me, thanks. It makes the graph; with the correct axes. However, I still want to know how to organize the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the coordinates together with the data:

```
data = Table[{x, t, Sin[2*Pi*x*(t - 4)]/x}, {x, .0001, 2, .1}, {t, 5, 
    6, 0.1}];

ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"t, time", "x, distance", "h, height"}]
```

[image: LisPlot3D]

Here I had to apply `Flatten` to the table so that all triples `{x, t, Sin[...]}` are at the same level of the list `data`.

Comment: Arrgh, ok I see. Thanks a lot. So it is just a list of data points, as data= {  {x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}, {x3,y3,z3}  }.

Comment: Yes, and for that reason the output of `Table` alone wouldn't work without `Flatten`.